# No module named 'encodings' error while starting uwsgi

Tags: python, django, nginx, centos7, uwsgi

I referred to following three links to upgrade python to 3.6.3 version and create virtual environment and then tried to server django via nginx/uwsgi. However, i'm struggling with the error saying "no module named encodings". 
If I used  below command then the django can be accessed. However, If run over the config file it will raise error saying "no module named encodings".

```
 "uwsgi --http :8080 --home /home/testuser1/myproject --chdir 
/home/testuser1/myprojecttss -w myprojecttss.wsgi
 "
```

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-centos-7#setting-up-the-uwsgi-application-server

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-uwsgi-and-nginx-to-serve-python-apps-on-centos-7#set-up-an-app-directory-and-a-virtualenv

Error Log:

```
 (myproject) [test@VM_134_114_centos ~]$ systemctl status uwsgi -l
 * uwsgi.service - uWSGI Emperor service
  Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Active: active (running) since Sat 2018-01-20 20:29:47 CST; 9min ago
  Main PID: 11381 (uwsgi)
  Status: "The Emperor is governing 0 vassals"
    CGroup: /system.slice/uwsgi.service
       `-11381 /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites

Jan 20 20:38:16 VM_134_114_centos uwsgi[11381]: uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /run/uwsgi/myprojecttss.sock fd 3
Jan 20 20:38:16 VM_134_114_centos uwsgi[11381]: uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
Jan 20 20:38:16 VM_134_114_centos uwsgi[11381]: setuid() to testuser1
Jan 20 20:38:16 VM_134_114_centos uwsgi[11381]: Python version: 3.6.3 (default, Jan 17 2018, 14:02:51)  [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)]
Jan 20 20:38:16 VM_134_114_centos uwsgi[11381]: Set PythonHome to /home/testuser1/myproject
Jan 20 20:38:16 VM_134_114_centos uwsgi[11381]: Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
Jan 20 20:38:16 VM_134_114_centos uwsgi[11381]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
Jan 20 20:38:16 VM_134_114_centos uwsgi[11381]: Current thread 0x00007fb1c7a04840 (most recent call first):
Jan 20 20:38:16 VM_134_114_centos uwsgi[11381]: Sat Jan 20 20:38:16 2018 - [emperor] curse the uwsgi instance myprojecttss.ini (pid: 12256)
Jan 20 20:38:16 VM_134_114_centos uwsgi[11381]: Sat Jan 20 20:38:16 2018 - [emperor] removed uwsgi instance myprojecttss.ini
```

uwsgi config file:

```
 [uwsgi]
 project = myprojecttss
 username = testuser1
 base = /home/%(username)
 env = myproject

 chdir = %(base)/%(project)
 module = %(project).wsgi
 home = %(base)/%(env)
 ##module = %(project).wsgi:application
 master = true
 processes = 5
 binary-path = %(base)/%(env)/bin/uwsgi
 #virtualenv = %(base)/%(env)
 uid = %(username)
 socket = /run/uwsgi/%(project).sock
 chown-socket = %(username):nginx
 chmod-socket = 775
 vacuum = true
 die-on-term = true
```

uwsgi service:

```
    [Unit]
      Description=uWSGI Emperor service

    [Service]
    ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/bash -c 'mkdir -p /run/uwsgi; chown testuser1:nginx /run/uwsgi'
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c 'cd /home/testuser1/myprojcettss; source /home/testuser1/myproject/bin/activate; uwsgi --ini  /etc/uwsgi/sites/myprojecttss.ini'
   Restart=always
   KillSignal=SIGQUIT
   Type=notify
   NotifyAccess=all

  [Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Do you have PYTHONPATH environment also set somewhere?

Comment: where can I find PYTHONPATH settings?

Comment: Looking at it again, are you using virtual environment? Can you make sure the uwsgi is specific to the environment of the project?

Comment: I am having the same issue -- virtualenv for python3.6 variable set in the uwsgi config. Uwsgi keeps using python3.5, perhaps a factor.